# workmanager on bootreceived

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-workmanager

I am trying to start, why the work manager won't start onbootreceived?

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().build();

PeriodicWorkRequest saveRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker.class, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .addTag("activation")
    .build();

OneTimeWorkRequest otr = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker.class).build();
WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWork();
WorkManager.getInstance().pruneWork();

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("activation", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, saveRequest);
```

Comment: `Log.d("testingworkmanager", "bootreceived");` is it working ?

Comment: yes its working thats interesting in bootreceive but not in uploadworker class

Comment: i have fixed it but it dowork runs about 15 times at start

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code:

1. You don't specify any constraints
2. doWork should return Result.success()/Result.failure()/Result.retry()
   If you want to return data you should use this API:
   public static Result success(@NonNull Data outputData)

Comment: actually its running but only one time now even if i set  periodic work to 1 min interval, i have updated my code

Comment: the minimum interval for periodic worker is 15mins. It might be the cause of your issue

public static final long MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS

The minimum interval duration for PeriodicWorkRequest (in milliseconds).

Constant Value: 900000 (0x00000000000dbba0)